# jackson-module-scala (play): registerModule(DefaultScalaModule): found DefaultScalaModule.type; required: databind.Module

Tags: scala, serialization, playframework, jackson, marshalling

I am trying to un/marshall json in a play app, by using [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) and their example:

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
```

I included these libraries in `Build.scala`

```
"com.fasterxml" % "jackson-module-scala" % "1.9.3",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.3.0",
```

and imported:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
```

However, when I run the Play App, I get the following error:

```
[error]  found   : com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.type
[error]  required: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module
[error]     mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)


play.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[type mismatch;
 found   : com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.type
 required: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(PlayReloader.scala:304) ~[na:na]
    at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(PlayReloader.scala:298) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was finally able to figure it out.

I was trying to get the latest version of `jackson-module-scala`; the latest version seemed to be `1.9.3` by checking: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/jackson-module-scala

However the proper place to look had the proper newest version `2.3.0`: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala_2.10

It was fixed by changing the `Build.scala` to:

```
...
"com.fasterxml" % "jackson-module-scala_2.10" % "2.3.0",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.3.0",
...
```

or even better use "%%" (for automatic scala version resolution; don't need to add "_scala.ver"):

```
...
"com.fasterxml" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.3.0",
"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.3.0",
...
```